# Sencha Touch 2 Grid

Tags: javascript, php, sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.4.1 (free version) and I want to create a grid in a view.

Is it possible?
And if so, how can I create it?
In some forums I have read that this is only possible in the purchase version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for you will be TouchTreeGrid: https://github.com/swluken/TouchTreeGrid